# Firebase Query Collection And Merge Subcollection Data

Tags: firebase, promise, async-await, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to figure out a way to get a collection of documents along with their subcollection data.

For example, my tree is...

```
-locations
 -{locationId}
   -historic
     -april
       -airTemp: 12.4
       -displayOrder: 4
     -august
       -airTemp: 14.5
       -displayOrder: 9
     -december
       -airTemp: 13.5
       -displayOrder: 12
     etc..
```

...where `locationId` is a document and `historic` is the subcollection with monthly documents in it.

I know how to get the top level collection items and store it into an array but I want to add their subcollection data (i.e. the jan, feb, etc.) into each document as well.

```
  var locations = []

  let ref = db.collection('locations')
  db.collection('locations').get()
  .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          let location = doc.data()
          location.id = doc.id
          location.name = doc.name

          // get the historic subcollection data here

      })
  })
```

How can I get the combined data (collection and subcollection) from each object and then push it into an array?

***bounty is wrong structure***
each month should be its own object

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to add their subcollection data (i.e. the jan, feb) into each document as well". Do you mean in the database OR in you frontend while reading the database?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec in the front end while reading the database

Answer (score 4):

There is no way, with the mobile/web client libraries, to get, **in one query**, the data of a Firestore document and the data of its sub-collection(s) documents.

There is even no way to get the list of the sub-collections of a document (with the mobile/web client libraries), see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document

So you need to know the name of the sub-collections in order to query them, which is your case (name = 'historic').

You could do as follows. First you get all the parent documents and at the same time you use `Promise.all()` to query, in parallel, all the 'historic' sub-collections.

```
    var db = firebase.firestore();

    var promises = []
    db.collection('locations').get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                let location = doc.data()
                location.id = doc.id
                location.name = doc.data().name
                console.log(location);
                promises.push(doc.ref.collection('historic').get());
            })
            return Promise.all(promises);
        })
        .then(results => {
            results.forEach(querySnapshot => {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                });
            });
        });
```

Note that the order of the `results` array is exactly the same than the order of the `promises` array.

Also note that to get the value of a document item (e.g. `name`) you need to do `doc.data().name` and not `doc.name`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  So I can see that this logs still the location and results as separate.  How would you get each location with the subsequent subcollection into 1 object?

Comment: You have to combine the result of the queries, knowing that the order of the results and promises arrays are the same.

Comment: Not really sure how to do that - that was the main issue I had when trying to tackle this.

Comment: With the first `.then(snapshot => {})` you will loop over the main docs. You can populate an array of these docs data there. Then in the `results.forEach(querySnapshot => {})` you will loop over the sub-collections. If you know the number of sub-collections of each parent doc it is quite easy (for example let's imagine you have 2 collections for each doc -jan and feb- , you know that the two first elements of the results array are corresponding to the first main document, and so on.

Comment: If the number of sub-collections is different for each parent doc you could store (in the parent doc) the number of collections in a dedicated field and use this value while looping on the `results array members to identify the parent doc of each historic doc. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks Renaud, they are a specific number of subcollections per document (12) 1 for each month. ill try to figure out how to merge these 1 arrays

Comment: Good luck! One last piece of advice: I will give the ID 01, 02, 03 to the months documents, in order to get them in the good order. Do not hesitate to ask if you need some more help. You may also consider accepting my answer ;-) Thanks.

Comment: Really appreciate the help and advice.  I think this is the most important part of the question tho and needs to be addressed before an answer is confirmed

Comment: @pmanning Hi, by the way did you succeed implementing the desired solution? You may accept my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

First create an empty array, e.g. `resultsArray = []`. Use simple or compound queries to get at the documents that you want to read. Then iterate over the resultDocuments creating an `resultObject` recording whatever properties you want. Inside that iteration, `.push(resultObject)` to the results array.