# Joining collection and sub-collection in firestore (web)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm playing around trying to learn Firestore and I'm experiencing some issues regarding joining data from a collection and a sub-collection. The name of the sub-collection is known `players`.

```
-match_stats (collection)
  |_ document with random ID
    |_ map (field - string)
    |_ scorehome (field - Number)
    |_ scoreaway (field - Number)
      |_ Sub-collection (named: Players)
        |_ documents with random ids
          |_ Field (Player names, ex. Christopher)
            |_ playerkills
            |_ playerdeaths
```

I've been able to `console.log` each collection separately, but I want the collection and the sub collection to be included in the same object, so I can combine the data. I'm also open to other suggestions on how to solve this problem.

[image: Result of console.log]

```html
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebase.firestore();

export default {
  data() {
    return {

      matchInfo: [],

    };
  },
  methods: {
    readMatches() {
      this.matchInfo = [];
      db.collection("match_stats")
      .get()
      .then(matchQuerysnapshot => {
        matchQuerysnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
          console.table(doc.data());
          db.collection("match_stats").doc(doc.id).collection("players")
          .get()
          .then(playersQuerySnapshot => {
            playersQuerySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            console.table(doc.data());
            })
          })
        })
      })
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.readMatches();
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do as follows. First you get all the parent documents and at the same time you use Promise.all() to query, in parallel, all the `players` sub-collections.

```
    var db = firebase.firestore();

    var promises = []
    db.collection('match_stats').get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                ...
                promises.push(doc.ref.collection('players').get());
            })
            return Promise.all(promises);
        })
        .then(results => {
            results.forEach(querySnapshot => {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                });
            });
        });
```

Note that the order of the `results` array is exactly the same than the order of the `promises` array.

I based my answer on this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52944587/firebase-query-collection-and-merge-subcollection-data) making changes to adapt to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Fire store has its own hook for grabbing data while page loads.

```
data() {
    return {

      matchInfo: [],

    };
  },
firestore() {
      return {
        matchInfo: db.collection('players')
        ... The rest of your code ...        

      }
    },
```